Unexpected Identifier Error in dbt (VS Code) with BigQuery When Referencing Models
I'm working on a data transformation project using dbt within Visual Studio Code (VS Code), connected to a BigQuery database. I keep encountering an "unexpected identifier" error when trying to join two tables by referencing my dbt models. My goal is to join these two tables using the ref function to reference the models. However, I can't seem to get past this error.
Here’s the query I’m using in my dbt model:
WITH
lagerl23b_source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {{ ref("int_LAGERL23B") }}
),

kdinfo01p_source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {{ ref("stg_KDINFO1P") }}
)

Beide_Kombiniert AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM lagerl23b_source
    JOIN kdinfo01p_source
    ON lagerl23b_source.PROD2_Kundennummer = kdinfo01p_source.PROD2_Kundennummer
) SELECT * FROM Beide_Kombiniert

When I run this query, I receive the following error:
unexpected identifier

dbt is a client tool, not an RDBMS (i.e. what actually runs your SQL). What RDBMS are you using?

You're missing a comma after the 2nd CTE. Try the following:
WITH

lagerl23b_source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {{ ref ("int_LAGERL23B") }}

),


kdinfo01p_source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {{ ref("stg_KDINFO1P") }}


),


Beide_Kombiniert AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM lagerl23b_source
    Join 
    kdinfo01p_source
    on lagerl23b_source.PROD2_Kundennummer = kdinfo01p_source.PROD2_Kundennummer
)

SELECT *
FROM Beide_Kombiniert

